# How to create http authorization for folder in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, authorization

In my project I have asp.net (webform) site, lets say, in folder `/site/...`
I have created an additional service : `/service/file.ashx`
and I need to protect this file by http authorization.

I've choosen authentication section for folder «service» in IIS7, and turned anonymouse off and basic on.

So, now, if I go just `/service/` then it's ok and standard http auth dialog comes up, but it doesn't work for `/service/file.ashx` — it's redirecting me to site's auth form (and if I'm already authorized then it mere processes file.ashx with no asking of authorization)

What do I have to do for making this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `location section with path property` on your `system.web section` and define `deny and allow sections`

```
<configuration>
   <location path="....">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: i tried, but it just gave me «500 - Internal server error.» when i'd added <location path="....">

Comment: there was no error message, just «500 - Internal server error.»

Comment: Actually, i've already figured out — i needed just to convert folder to application, then copied bin folder, and it bagan working properly. Anywaym thanx for advicing

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve my problem:
i couldnt turn off form auth because it was inherited from root web.config, so i copied web.config to folder /site/ with only auth section, and removed from root web.config. It allowed me to adjust web.config of /Dod/ folder and then it worked out :)

Comment: shit, no, it failed. It turned on http authorizaton for «/service/» folder and files, and it worked ok, but the main site stopped working (with 500 error)

Comment: i've figured out — i needed just to convert folder to application, then copied bin folder, and it bagan working properly.